# Should a parentAuthenticationManager in Spring AuthenticationManagerBuilder return null or throw an Exception?

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm chaining two AuthenticationManagers using AuthenticationManagerBuilder.parentAuthenticationManager in a Spring Configuration.
I did not find any best practices article pointing out whether to throw a BadCredentialsException() or to return null if the respective manager could not validate the login.
Currently this would not make much of a difference since the throwing Manager is last in the chain but I wonder how Spring might handle this if more then one Manager is added.